# How to set 'ref' from value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile-development

I'm trying to set TextInput 'ref' from value.
Example:

```js
var testtest = 'testvalue'
<TextInput
ref=testtest
autoCapitalize="none"
autoCorrect={false}
autoFocus={false}
placeholderTextColor="#b8b8b8"
color="#b8b8b8"
multiline={true}
onFocus={(() => this.onFieldFocus(testtest))}
style={styles.textInput}
/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want something like this:

```
const testtest = 'testvalue'

class TestComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, ctx) {
    super(props, ctx);

    this.onFieldFocus = this.onFieldFocus.bind(this);
  }

  onFieldFocus() {
    const textInput = this.refs[testtest];
  }

  render() {
    return <TextInput ref={testtest} onFocus={this.onFieldFocus} />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every argument that comes from a variable must be inside brackets.

You should therefore have `ref={testtest}`

You would then access it through `this.refs[testtest]`

However I am curious about what use-case would need to have dynamic ref.

Comment: What about onfocus? I need to write onFocus={(() => this.onFieldFocus({testtest}))} ?

Comment: onFocus = {this.onFieldFocus.bind(this, testtest)} Seems much cleaner to me

Comment: I think that comment was on adding a second set of curlies around `testtest`. The answer is no, you don't have to add a second set of curlies once you're already inside one pair. Think of it as using the curlies to go back into javascript world. If you were to put in JSX again inside the curlies then you'd need a second set but in this case, one is enough